# How to loop through an array and display data within the object of that array, in react and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have an array like this one I want to loop through it and display the data that's inside the objects, any idea how I can do that?

```
layout: [
    [{
        type: 'text',
        value: 'abc'
    }],
    [{
        type: 'text',
        value: 'def'
    }],
    [
        {
            type: 'text',
            value: '123'
        },
        {}
    ]
]
```

And here is my loop:

```
const {layout} = this.state
let rows = []
for (let i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {
    rows.push(<div className="row" key={i}>
    </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array like, and call it by their index like the example below

```js
let layout= [
            [
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    value: 'abc'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    value: 'def'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    value: '123'
                },
                {}
            ]
        ];

         let rows = [];
         var div = document.createElement('div');
         for (let i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {
             rows.push('<div className="row" key={i}></div>');
             var s = '<li>'+layout[i][0].type+': '+layout[i][0].value+'</li>'; 
             document.body.innerHTML +=s;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, layout[i][0].type simple logic is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you get a number to work with. In this case, `i`. You can access the contents of `i` with `layout[i]`. Push that to your `rows` object inside the `div`, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yogishb608/s5tamnfy/3/)
React Solution

`<div>{(layout).map(function(data){
                return(
                data.map(function(data){
                return(
                    <div>
                      {data.type+
                      "\n"

                      +data.value
                      }
                  </div>
                )
              })
          )
    })}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map):

```
layout.map(row => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type={row.type} value={row.value} />
    </div>
  )
})
```

For a complete example with React, see : https://jsfiddle.net/gbourgin/wu737LLj/

Remark: I don't see why you need an array of array for your layout variable